# grep command with ls -a not working properly?

Tags: grep, ls

I was trying to list some hidden files in my home directory and I encountered a very odd behavior of `grep` command when combining with `ls` command.

1. I executed `ls -a` on my home directory and got all the files
   including hidden files as expected.
2. I wanted to list all the **hidden files** starting with 'xau' so I executed `ls -a |grep -i .xau*` and it also worked as expected.
3. Then I executed `ls -a |grep -i .x*` in the same directory but **it
   didn't list anything at all**.
4. I then mistakenly typed `ls -a |grep -i .*x` **(note that this time wildcard character * and character 'x' have switched places)** and the interesting thing is that it behaved like what I intended in step3. I tried the same thing with this command `ls -a .*x` and `ls -a .*X` but I get *no such file or directory* error.

[image]

[image]

I have added the actual text output [here.](https://anotepad.com/notes/eftm8q)

Some of you may ask why not just use `ls -a .x*` but the thing with `grep` is that it prints with the appropriate colors. So could anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Can you please paste *actual text* rather than a screenshot?

Comment: Doe, the answer you've accepted gives you a command to use which will show you **every** file in the current directory.  I don't think that's what you want.  Please comment on [my answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315259/135943) if I'm wrong.

Comment: A question mark (`?`) in regular expressions means "zero or one of the preceding character"; it doesn't mean "any single character."  There are *two* "main things."  (As I mentioned earlier, in my answer.)  ;)

Comment: Thank you Wildcard. `ls -a | grep -i '^\.x'` seems to be the correct way to search, in my case

Comment: [Don't parse `ls`](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128987/136107), don't [do it](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs), mkay?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why \*not\* parse \`ls\`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are suffering from **premature glob expansion.**

`.xa*` doesn't expand because it doesn't match anything in the current directory.  (Globs are case sensitive.)  However, `.x*` *does* match some files, so this gets expanded by the shell before `grep` ever sees it.

When `grep` receives multiple arguments, it assumes the first is the pattern and the remainder are files to search for that pattern.

So, in the command `ls -a | grep -i .x*`, the output of `ls` is *ignored*, and the file ".xsession-errors.old" is searched for the pattern ".xsession-errors".  Not surprisingly, nothing is found.

To prevent this, put your special characters within single or double quotes.  For example:

```
ls -a | grep -i '.x*'
```

---

You are also suffering from **regex vs. glob confusion.**

You seem to be looking for files that start with the literal string ".x" and are followed by anything—but regular expressions don't work the same as file globs.  The `*` *in regex* means "the preceding character zero or more times," not "any sequence of characters" as it does in file globs.  So what you *probably* want is:

```
ls -a | grep -i '^\.x'
```

This searches for files whose names *start* with the literal characters ".x", or ".X".  Actually since there's only one letter you are specifying, you could just as easily use a character class rather than `-i`:

```
ls -a | grep '^\.[xX]'
```

The point is that **regular expressions are very different from file globs.**

If you just try `ls -a | grep -i '.x*'`, as has been suggested, you will be very surprised to see that EVERY file will be shown!  (The same output as `ls -a` directly, except placed on separate lines as in `ls -a -1`.)

How come?

Well, in *regex* (but not in shell globs), a period (`.`) means "any single character."  And an asterisk (`*`) means "zero or more of the preceding character."  So that the regex `.x*` means "any character, followed by zero or more instances of the character 'x'."

Of course, you are not allowed to have null file names, so *every* file name contains "a character followed by at least zero 'x's."  :)

---

**Summary:**

To get the results you want, you need to understand two things:

1. Unquoted special glob characters (including `*`, `?`, `[]` and some others) will get expanded *by the shell* before the command you are running ever *sees* them, and
2. Regular expressions are different from (and more powerful than) file globs.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you do not enclose `*` in quotes and make shell expand it before running a command. See:

```
$ touch .xau1 .xau2
# this won't work
$ ls -a | grep -i .xau*
# but this does
$ ls -a | grep -i ".xau*"
.xau1
.xau2
# this one too
$ ls -a | grep -i '.xau*'
.xau1
.xau2
# check what shell sees
$ ls -a | grep -i .xau* # now don't press enter but C-x * and you'll see this:
$ ls -a | grep -i .xau1 .xau2
```