# Command ls | grep showing only directories ( when it should also show files)

Tags: linux, grep

In linux, I have a files contains, amongst other, lots of files and directories containing the literal "scrap".
I can see them by typing `ls *scrap*` without problem. However that returns also directories containing the literal "scrap" and i would like to exclude those.

I tried playing around with `ls | grep ".*scrap.*"` or `ls | grep scrap` but this returns only the directories (not the normal files).

Why is this so?

The next step will be (once the rep returns the correct output) to remove the directories from that output. Suggestions on how to do that are also welcomed!

Comment: The last paragraph is the actual question here, right ? The rest is a typical example of [XY question...](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/233676#233676)

Comment: "but this returns only the directories (not the normal files)" I cannot reproduce that.

Comment: The meaning of the first sentance in your question is a little unclear (for me):"In linux, I have a files contains, amongst other, lots of files and directories containing the literal "scrap"."

Comment: Whoops. The meaning of the first sentence in your question is a little unclear (for me): 'In linux, I have a files contains, amongst other, lots of files and directories containing the literal "scrap".' Are you talking about files and/or directories that exist and have the string "scrap" in their names? Or are you describing a file that contains a list of files and/or directory names? If "ls | grep scrap" only returns directories, then there are only directories with scrap in their names. As others mentioned, it might be better to describe just your ultimate goal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, to eventually list all regular files in the current directory (on the 1st level) which have `scrap` in their names, you don't need `ls` + `grep`.

With old good **`find`** command:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*scrap*" -ls
```

Comment: im asking with `grep` because in the end i want to move the files that are found with grep using `mv | grep scrap scraping`

Comment: @jimbasquiat, no problem with that: use find's `-exec` action as `-exec mv ...`

Comment: just tried the suggestion `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name "*scrap*" -ls` but it does not return any result. I tried `ls *scrap*` again, which works as intended

Comment: @jimbasquiat, you may omit `-ls` action

Comment: I also did that but still no results... `find . -maxdepth 1` works fine as well. It is when i tried to add the name flag with `find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*scrap*"` that it starts returning only the directories... It is supposed to reutn everything but directories, to be clear

Comment: @jim it you update your question to explain what you want to achieve, rather then seeking a solution to one way of getting there, you might well get some more optimal solutions being offered

Answer (score 1):

You run into problems with `ls` and `grep` when file names contain spaces or (worse) newlines. But with safe file names you can do this:

```
ls -l | grep -oP '^-.* \K.*$'
ls -l | sed -n '/^-/s/^.* //p'
```

But usually you should use the `find` approach.

Answer (score 0):

For the names of the non-directory files in the current directory that contain `scrap`, in `zsh`:

```
print -rC1 -- *scrap*(ND^/)
```

Note that in `ls *scrap*` (or the more correct `ls -- *scrap*`), if any of the `*scrap*` files are of type *directory*, then `ls` will list their *contents* (with a `that-scrap-dir:` header unless `*scrap*` expand into one and only one file that is that directory).

If you want that for files of type *directory*, `ls` just prints their name like for other types of files, you'd need to add the `-d` option:

```
ls -d -- *scap*(D^/)
```

But there's hardly any point using `ls` as all the work of finding files by name and type has been done by the shell by the time `ls` is invoked, you might as well use the builtin `print` or `printf` of your shell.

Answer (score -2):

Seems like [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/315259) is the answer you're looking for.
The post speaks into glob expansion being the reason why only certain things are showing.